# How Can I Read this Array Code? using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have one code, I cannot imagine, how can I read this array, using php. please help me to..

```
array(
    'serialize_data' => array(
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_0', value => '81112890V'),
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_1', value => '822312890V'),
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_2', value => '873312110V'),
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_3', value => '873312890V')
    )
);
```

Comment: I can't even read that array with my bare eyes :)

Comment: Thanks every one...!! hey guys..!! i need capture those values using PHP code...help me babies ...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach($array as $key=>$value){`

```
echo $value[0]['name'];
echo $value[0]['value'];
```

`}`

use above line to print your array element, like index number 0.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
print_r($your-array);
```

?

To access individual levels it looks like you need to go down a level or two. I.e.

```
echo $your-array['serialize_data'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: No I need have to capture those array values...please help me to solve this ...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use following method.

```
$array = array(
    'serialize_data' => array(
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_0', value => '81112890V'),
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_1', value => '822312890V'),
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_2', value => '873312110V'),
        array('name' => 'cadidate_id_3', value => '873312890V')
    )
);

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
}
```

using this method you can read or access its name and value by passing the index number.
like:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($value[0]); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: No,this is not i want.,please hel me MOHIT !!!

Comment: please check the answer.. i have updated my previous one.

Comment: Mohit,Please i need have to use ECHO Statement,Not print_r method..can you provide.that.any way.i m so happy to deal with you..

Comment: Thanks Mohit.Actually i need have to put AUTOMATED index number here.simply says  echo $value[$index]['name']; .,please can you edit your code..!!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
//grab array of name and value
$array=$data-array['serialize_data']
//traverse
foreach($nv as $array)
{
    $name=$nv['name'];
    $value=$nv['value'];
    //do something to name
    print $name;
    //do something to value
    print $value;
}
```

Comment: can you provide me foreach(){} example....can you do that ?? please

Comment: corrected.. it's for-each 

for fruitful example visit 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp
http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php